# Automatically show result when option is selected in Drop Down List

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu

I want to show the result automatically when an option (from Drop Down List) is selected by the user, without using Submit in form, i.e. Just choose the option and the result is here. And by default (if user doen't choose any option and want to see full list) "All" option should be selected.

In my code, only "Strategy" option is showing and also doesn't changing on choosing any other option.

Code is:

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function selectOption() {
                var option = document.form1.genre.value;
                if (option == "All") { <? php $abc = mysql_query("select * from games where pc='yes'"); ?>
                        'games'
                    is the name of the table in my database

                    return true;
                } else if (option == "Action / Mission") { <? php $abc = mysql_query("select * from games where pc='yes' and genre='Action / Mission'"); ?>
                    return true;
                } else if (option == "Racing") { <? php $abc = mysql_query("select * from games where pc='yes' and genre='Racing'"); ?>
                    return true;
                } else if (option == "Sports") { <? php $abc = mysql_query("select * from games where pc='yes' and genre='Sports'"); ?>
                    return true;
                } else if (option == "Strategy") { <? php $abc = mysql_query("select * from games where pc='yes' and genre='Strategy'"); ?>
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="genre" onChange="selectOption()">
                        <option value="All">All</option>
                        <option value="Action / Mission">Action / Mission</option>
                        <option value="Racing">Racing</option>
                        <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
                        <option value="Strategy">Strategy</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

I doubt this line

```
var option=document.form1.genre.value;
```

Please correct where I m wrong

Comment: just create an ajax call on the server

Comment: search search here, in google or SO: `ajax javascript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a ID to the select element. Ex : id="genre"

And then use :

```
var x = document.getElementById("genre").value;
alert("You selected: " + x);
```

Comment: <select name="genre" onChange="selectOption()">
here change name to id
<select id="genre" onChange="selectOption()">

and then var option = document.form1.genre.value;
change it to 
var option = document.getElementById("genre").value;

Comment: Thanks for your answer but after doing so same error occurs. In my question only last if condition is processing, i.e. if I m validating the condition then only the last one                     "else if (option == "Strategy") { <? php $abc = mysql_query("select * from games where pc='yes' and genre='Strategy'"); ?>"               is showing no after choosing any other value, nothing happens, same result. Suggestion please
                    return true;

Comment: Hi Please post a jsfiddle for this. It will be helpful. And did you put an alert and see if the option you are getting now is correct. If the option is correct, then I will check the if else for the error

Comment: I have posted a question regarding this. Link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917030/get-data-from-php-validate-in-javascript-function-and-echo-automatically-on-cho   Helpless to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make it in this way

```
<select name="genre" onChange="selectOption(this.value)">
```

And in your javascript use as

```
function selectOption(option_selected){
var option=document.form1.genre.value; // remove this line
if(option_selected== "All"){
--
--
```

Comment: var option=document.form1.genre.value; remove this line

Answer (score 0):

first of all `you don't have form1` then how you can use it.

you can achieve what you want by ajax.see a small demo.

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function selectOption() {
                var option = document.getElementById('genre').value;
                alert(option);

                $.ajax({
                 type:'post',
                 url:'submit.php',// construct sql in this page and return the data to be shown .you can get the option on submit page using $_POST['option']
                 data:{option:option},
                success:function(data){
                   alert('got it');// show data here 
                },


                });

            }
        </script>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select id="genre" onChange="selectOption()">
                        <option value="All">All</option>
                        <option value="Action / Mission">Action / Mission</option>
                        <option value="Racing">Racing</option>
                        <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
                        <option value="Strategy">Strategy</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: your answer satisfied me almost but only two things are confusing.         1. In your answer your lines from $ajax({ ------ to ----alert('got it'); is not clear. Please tell me that where to validate, that is, if(option = "All"){condition}.                            2. I forgot to mention in my code that i m using "form", thats y i have given "form1" name in my query.

Comment: based on option you are constructing the sql so submit.php or whatever name you want to give to your file(function) will have sql based on the option passed.get the resultant array from there and echo $phpdata  in submit.php.you will get that in success: data use jquery/javascript to display on page.no need of form in this situation.

Comment: I have posted a question regarding this. Link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917030/get-data-from-php-validate-in-javascript-function-and-echo-automatically-on-cho   Need help to solve my issue.