# GET data from php, validate in javascript function and echo automatically on choosing the value of DropDown

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu

I want to GET data from php, validate in javascript function and echo automatically on choosing the value of DropDown, without any Submit, i.e. just choose the value and the result is here.

By default (till user doesn't choose any category "--Select Genre--") All games list should be shown.

Code is:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die('Localhost Connection Problem');
mysql_select_db('gamezone')or die('Database Error');
?>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectOption(){
var val = document.getElementById('genre').value;
if(val == "Racing")
{
<?php $abc=mysql_query("select * from games where genre='Racing'"); ?>
```

--------Here i want to validate from php that if the genre is Racing then echo list of that games--------

```
}
else if val =="Sports")
{
<?php $abc=mysql_query("select * from games where genre='Sports'"); ?>
}
else if val =="Strategy")
{
<?php $abc=mysql_query("select * from games where genre='Strategy'"); ?>
}
else {
return false;}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">
```

Do I need  or its extra in this code?

```
        <select id="genre" onChange="selectOption()">
        <option value="">--Select Genre--</option>
        <option value="Racing">Racing</option>
        <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
        <option value="Strategy">Strategy</option>
        </select>
        </form>
<?php
$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($abc))
{
$i= $i+1;
?>
<?php echo $i; ?>
<?php echo $row['game']; ?>
<?php echo $row['genre']; ?>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should be using an ajax request to a php file based on the value of the dropdown onChange. Using Jquery to do such is pretty easy and you'll find tons of examples online.

Comment: 5 cents. It's a bad approach to mix everything (HTML rendering, backend, requests to DB ) in one PHP file. Read about MVC, look at some frameworks like Codeigniter, Yii, etc...

Comment: i have used <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script> but don't know why its not working..

Answer (score 0):

first chage :

```
else if val =="Strategy")
```

to

```
else if (val =="Strategy") and other also.
```

and use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

look at this simple exemple to know how to use ajax requests :

**PHP :**

lets say this file is validation.php :

```
<?php 
   $var = $_GET['variable1'];
   //do you work here 
   die("good");//or die('bad'); according to your validation
 ?>
```

**JS :**

```
   $.get(
    'validation.php',//path to your php validation file
    {
    variable1 : 'value'//the name  of the get variable sent
    },
    function(data){//call back function
       //data here contains what the validation.php file returned
       if(data=="good"){
       //do good stuff
       }else if(data=="bad"){
      //do bad stuff
       }
    );

   }
```

Comment: i have used <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script> but don't know why its not working..